# How do you get `npm prune --production` to operate recursively?

Tags: node.js, npm

Seems like a fairly straightforward thing, but I can't find anything on the interwebs.

It appears that `npm prune --production` only descends into the current package's `node_modules` folder.  However, it does *not* recurse down the `node_modules` tree to remove `devDependencies` recursively.  The result is that my project is a bit smaller in size thanks to the removal of its *direct* `devDependencies`, but the `devDependencies` of the project remain transitively, leaving it unnecessarily large in real projects.

Behavior is identical from `npm` versions `6.4.1` through `6.14.4`.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, figured it out, with not much help from the npm documentation.

To install only `dependencies` (that is, *production* dependencies only) recursively, you need two perform two steps:

1. Call `npm ci`.  That installs only `dependencies` among a project's transitive dependencies, but it also installs a project's direct `devDependencies`.
2. Call `npm prune --production`.  That gets rid of the top-level project's `devDependencies`.

With these steps, you can *immensely* reduce the size of your projects, which is helpful when they are deployables that create, say, Docker images.  If you make sure to include `RUN npm ci && npm prune --production` in your `Dockerfile`s, your final image will be much smaller than if you don't, thanks to a much smaller `node_modules` directory.